# Save profile form - Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, web

### I have Profile component and Profile-detail. I would like save the date(after press button) from Profile form to  a card in profile detail.

This is my Profile form:

```html
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Profilo</h5>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="photo">Carica una foto</label>
        <input type="file" id="photo" accept="image/*" class="form-control" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
        <!-- Mostra l'immagine selezionata -->
        <img *ngIf="userImageUrl" [src]="userImageUrl" alt="Immagine del profilo" class="img-fluid mt-2">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input #inputName placeholder="Nome" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea #inputDescription placeholder="Descrizione" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input #inputEmail placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input #inputTelefono placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input #inputCompetenze placeholder="Competenze (separate da virgola)" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input #inputInteressi placeholder="Interessi (separati da virgola)" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input #inputLinkedIn placeholder="LinkedIn" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input #inputTelegram placeholder="Telegram" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input #inputInstagram placeholder="Instagram" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <button (click)="onContinueClick()" class="btn btn-warning">Continua</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have this ts.
ts:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from '../services/profile.service';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profilo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profilo.component.css']
})
export class ProfiloComponent {
  @ViewChild('inputName') inputName: any;
  @ViewChild('inputDescription') inputDescription: any;
  @ViewChild('inputEmail') inputEmail: any;
  @ViewChild('inputTelefono') inputTelefono: any;
  @ViewChild('inputCompetenze') inputCompetenze: any;
  @ViewChild('inputInteressi') inputInteressi: any;
  @ViewChild('inputLinkedIn') inputLinkedIn: any;
  @ViewChild('inputTelegram') inputTelegram: any;
  @ViewChild('inputInstagram') inputInstagram: any;

  @Output() dataSaved = new EventEmitter<void>();

  userImageUrl: string | null = null;
  profileForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private profileService: ProfileService,
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [''], // Inizializza con valori predefiniti se necessario
      email: [''],
      // Altri campi del form
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Recupera i dati del profilo dalla route attiva
    const state = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('state');

    if (state) {
      const profileData = JSON.parse(state);
      this.inputName.nativeElement.value = profileData.name;
      this.inputDescription.nativeElement.value = profileData.description;
      this.inputEmail.nativeElement.value = profileData.email;
      this.inputTelefono.nativeElement.value = profileData.telefono;
      this.inputCompetenze.nativeElement.value = profileData.competenze.join(', ');
      this.inputInteressi.nativeElement.value = profileData.interessi.join(', ');
      this.inputLinkedIn.nativeElement.value = profileData.linkedin;
      this.inputTelegram.nativeElement.value = profileData.telegram;
      this.inputInstagram.nativeElement.value = profileData.instagram;
      this.userImageUrl = profileData.imageUrl;
    }
  }

  onContinueClick() {
    const data = {
      name: this.inputName.nativeElement.value,
      description: this.inputDescription.nativeElement.value,
      email: this.inputEmail.nativeElement.value,
      telefono: this.inputTelefono.nativeElement.value,
      competenze: this.inputCompetenze.nativeElement.value,
      interessi: this.inputInteressi.nativeElement.value,
      linkedin: this.inputLinkedIn.nativeElement.value,
      telegram: this.inputTelegram.nativeElement.value,
      instagram: this.inputInstagram.nativeElement.value,
      imageUrl: this.userImageUrl,
    };
    this.profileService.updateProfileData(data);

    const competenzeArray = data.competenze.split(',').map(skill => skill.trim());
    const interessiArray = data.interessi.split(',').map(interest => interest.trim());

    this.firestore.collection('utenti', ref => ref.where('email', '==', data.email)).get().subscribe((querySnapshot) => {
      if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
        const existingUser = querySnapshot.docs[0];
        existingUser.ref.update({
          name: data.name,
          description: data.description,
          telefono: data.telefono,
          competenze: competenzeArray,
          interessi: interessiArray,
          linkedin: data.linkedin,
          telegram: data.telegram,
          instagram: data.instagram,
          imageUrl: data.imageUrl,
        }).then(() => {
          console.log('Dati del profilo aggiornati con successo in Firestore.');
          this.dataSaved.emit();
        });
      } else {
        this.firestore.collection('utenti').add({
          name: data.name,
          description: data.description,
          email: data.email,
          telefono: data.telefono,
          competenze: competenzeArray,
          interessi: interessiArray,
          imageUrl: data.imageUrl,
        }).then(() => {
          console.log('Nuovo utente aggiunto con successo in Firestore.');
          this.dataSaved.emit();
        });
      }
    });
    const formData = this.profileForm.value;
  }

  onFileSelected(event: any) {
    const file: File = event.target.files[0];

    const uniqueName = new Date().getTime() + '_' + file.name;

    const storageRef = this.storage.ref('/images/' + uniqueName);
    const uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);

    uploadTask.then((snapshot) => {
      storageRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
        this.userImageUrl = url;
      });
    });
  }

 

}
```

I would save the text thet I have add in this form (after click button) in a card in second component.
profile-detail: html:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <!-- Visualizza i dati del profilo -->
        <img [src]="profileData.imageUrl || 'URL_DEL_TUO_IMMAGINE_DEFAULT'" alt="Foto Utente" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ profileData.name }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Interessi:</strong></p>
          <ul class="card-text">
            <li *ngFor="let interest of profileData.interessi">{{ interest }}</li>
          </ul>
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Competenze:</strong></p>
          <ul class="card-text">
            <li *ngFor="let skill of profileData.competenze">{{ skill }}</li>
          </ul>
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Email:</strong> {{ profileData.email }}</p>
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Telefono:</strong> {{ profileData.telefono }}</p>
          <!-- Altri dettagli del profilo -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from '../services/profile.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-detail',
  templateUrl: './profile-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-detail.component.css']
})
export class ProfileDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  profileData: any; // Dati del profilo da visualizzare nella card

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Recupera i dati del profilo dal servizio condiviso
    this.profileService.profileData$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.profileData = data;
    });
  }
}
```

can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to get the user data from component A to populate the component B using a service? is it right? Can you include the service o just the `this.profileService.updateProfileData` function?

Comment: In my service i add these, but i don't think so getUserProfile(email: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.firestore.collection('utenti').doc(email).valueChanges();
  }

  // Metodo per aggiornare un profilo utente
  updateUserProfile(email: string, userData: any): Promise<void> {
    return this.firestore.collection('utenti').doc(email).set(userData, { merge: true });
  }

Comment: So you are using Firestore, i can't help.. BTW add this info to the question, it could be useful to know for other users